# how to upload a video to google driver use paperclip or carriwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg, paperclip

i want to upload video to google driver.
code models
video model

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :video,
   :storage => :google_drive,
   :google_drive_credentials => {:client_id => AppConfig.gg_drive.client_id,
                              :client_secret => AppConfig.gg_drive.client_secret,
                              :refresh_token => AppConfig.gg_drive.refresh_token,
                              :scope => AppConfig.gg_drive.scope,
                              :access_token => Token.cache_access_token_google_drive
                              },
  :styles => {
    :medium => {
      :geometry => "640x480",
      :format => 'mp4'
    },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10} 
  },# hello 123
  :processors => [:transcoder],
  :google_drive_options => {
    :path => proc { |style| "#{style}_#{id}_#{image.original_filename}" },
    :public_folder_id => '0B0VNyOkzIwUZZFFGeVhycFk0dnc'
  }
end
```

in Gemfile

```
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'paperclip-googledrive'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg"
```

in controller

```
def create
    if params[:videos]
      params[:videos].each { |video| Video.create(video: video) }
    end
end
```

when i run , this display error

> [AV] Running command: if command -v avprobe 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
>   [AV] Running command: if command -v ffmpeg 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
>      Av::UnableToDetect in AlbumsController#create
>   Unable to detect any supported library

pls. how to fix this errors

Comment: Have you installed libav and ffmpeg on your server? Are the `avprobe` and `ffmpeg` commands in the PATH?